# Java how to display the JTree File model if the application is jar file format

Tags: file, jar, jtree

I had an application with JTree will display the file in certain directory. After i export this application to jar file. The JTree can not read the file from the directory. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you bundle the file into the jar? If you're trying to get your application to run as .jar, you can't use resources that don't exist in that jar.